Problema al leer una columna de excel en Python
El código no sirve cuando intento leer una fecha en excel, con las demás variables funciona bien
import plotly
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

#Leer dataframe del archivo excel
df = pd.read_excel('Tasks.xlsx')
#Asignar columna to variable
tarea = df['Task']
inicio = df['Start']
print(inicio)


Buenas, puedes editar el código, seleccionarlo y ponerlo dentro de formato código ? el boton { }  de formato. Tienes todos los imports en la misma linea?

para validar nombres de columnas puedes hacer un print(df.info()) o un print([x for x in df.columns])
